# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export - popper.js error

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, popper.js, angular7

**Angular is giving the error:** *popper.js in bootstrap 4 gives SyntaxError Unexpected token export*

I'm getting this error from browser console.

Even I changed the popper.min.js location reference but no use..

node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js

node_modules/popper.js/dist/ems/popper.min.js

**Angular.json**

```
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
      "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js"
    ]
```

Comment: when I used to "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js" umd location it is giving this error- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined. For other reference it is working well esm and dist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrap.min.js is depend on the popper.min.js , change the order as follows,

```
   "scripts": [
     "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
     "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
   ]
```

Comment: Walaa it works. Thanks buddy, for your lightning fast reply.

Comment: Mark if the answer helpee

Comment: This answer helped me.  I had to change the order in my Bundle.Config as I was running the popper scripts first before the jquery scripts.  Cheers!